# How to inspect elements inside Iframe using IE Developer toolbar in IE7

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer, toolbar, internet-explorer-7

I have a web application, which uses Iframe. When I try to inspect element in IE developer toolbar, the Iframe node gets highlighted and it stops there. I can see an expand icon near the Iframe node. But when I double-click it, nothing happens.

After getting annoyed after many trial and errors, I tried testing it by creating a sample iframe in a new html page and there it was... i could see it getting all the elements inside the iframe.

So what happened to my web application then, does it depend upon any coding style.... I am completely blank about this issue.

As mentioned in title, I use IE Developer toolbar in IE7 in Vista.

Answer (score 47):

I had exactly the same problem, but seemed to resolve it by clicking on the refresh button in the IE developer toolbar pane.  Its the button which has a blue down/up arrow icon next to the disk icon.  If you click it, for some reason the DOM inspector seems to start working within the Iframe when previously it didn't.

Comment: Dude, I would give you +100 for this if I could.

Comment: FWIW, the same problem exists in IE 10 as well and @jaffa's workaround still applies.

Answer (score 2):

To build on jaffa's answer (and since I can't comment on jaffa's answer yet!): in my situation, the iframe is not available in IE dev tools without clicking that refresh button in the dev toolbar because the content of the iframe is loaded asynchronously.  It appears IE dev tools will have the DOM structure of the page at the time of loading, but if any changes happen thereafter, the dev tools must be refreshed.